# FreeIPA split in container

Tags: split, containers, freeipa

I am currently looking into the possibilities of FreeIPA and especially running it in containers.

My question is what parts of FreeIPA can run individually in containers without losing manageability or functionality of FreeIPA, in other words, is it modular?

The other question is, are there tutorials on how to do this for docker or OpenShift.

Thanks for the help and have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

FreeIPA can indeed be run in Docker Container. In fact, you can already find it's container at https://github.com/freeipa/freeipa-container.